# Specs implicit conversion conflicts with Scala Predef

Tags: scala, testing, types, implicit-conversion, specs

I have a type alias in my code like so:

```
type Time = Double
```

And I often in both tests and in applications pass Long values to functions that use this type. For instance:

```
 def at(time : Time) : T = {
     // Do Something
 }

 at(System.currentTimeMillis)
```

This code works fine unless run in my tests where I get the following error:

```
  found   : Long
  required: com.github.oetzi.echo.Echo.Time
  Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
  both method long2double in object Predef of type (x: Long)Double
  and method longToDouble in trait NumericBaseMatchers of type (s: Long)Double
  are possible conversion functions from Long to com.github.oetzi.echo.Echo.Time
```

After looking up `NumericBaseMatchers` it seems its part of the Specs testing framework (my tests are written in Specs 1). I tried running code to get the error in the interpreter and it was fine out side of the tests.

Is there any way I can somehow remove the ambiguity so I can pass Long to values to a Double/Time function? Why does Specs try and create its own LongToDouble conversion when Scala already provides this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deactivate an inherited implicit conversion you can do this:

```
  override def longToDouble(s: Long) = super.longToDouble(s)
```

For convenience if you add it to a new trait, you can mix-in your trait to your specification when needed:

```
  trait NoConversion {
    override def longToDouble(s: Long) = super.longToDouble(s)
  }

  class MySpecification extends NoConversion {
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unimporting one of them.

```
import NumericBaseMatchers.{longToDouble => _}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. NumericBaseMatchers is a trait. Importing complains that there is no companion object?